# How to get touched position of texture image on THREE.SphereGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to get touched position of threejs's `Object3D` (`THREE.SphereGeometry`).

I could get intersect object from `THREE.Raycaster` but what I really want is X/Y coordinates of the image which is used by Geometry as a Texture.

**How can I convert the intersect object to X/Y coordinates of the texture image of the sphere geometry?**

[image: I wish this image helps you understand this question.]

Thank you @prisoner849 and @Mugen87. I read your comments and tried `intersection.uv` after reading source code of [raycast texture sample](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=texture#webgl_raycast_texture).

But I could not get correct value from intersect object.

[Here is my sample app (Script will run after clicking `Detect Faces`)](https://arakaki.app/vr-images/view/3)

I created mesh object like:

```js
    const sphereMesh = (() => {
      const geometry = (() => {
        const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 64, 64);

        geometry.scale(1, 1, -1);
        geometry.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);

        return geometry;
      })();

      const material = (() => {
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          wireframe: true,
        });

        return material;
      })();

      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

      mesh.name = "sphere";

      return mesh;
    })();
```

then set texture on the material:

```js
    async function resetImageTexture() {
      const texture = new THREE.Texture();

      texture.image = previewImage;
      texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
      texture.needsUpdate = true;

      sphereMesh.material.wireframe = false;
      sphereMesh.material.map = texture;
    }
```

and get intersect object and converted to pixel coordinates.

```js
                  raycaster.setFromCamera(position, camera);

                  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(sphereMesh);

                  if (intersects[0]) {
                    const uv = sphereMesh.material.map.transformUv(intersects[0].uv);

                    previewCanvasContext.beginPath();
                    previewCanvasContext.arc(uv.x * previewCanvas.width, uv.y * previewCanvas.height, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    previewCanvasContext.closePath();
                    previewCanvasContext.fill();
                  }
```

but the result is:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=texture#webgl_raycast_texture

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you for your advise. But I could not get over the trouble with the example. I updated question. Can you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

The intersection object does not only contain the intersection point in 3D space. It also provides the texture coordinates at the point of intersection. This is documented in the respective [documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject).

So instead of accessing `intersection.point`, try it with `intersection.uv`.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I have not noticed the `uv` params in `intersection` object. But  I could not solve my problem yet. I updated my question. Could you check my question again, please? I need your help again.

Comment: @KatzNigaki Why are you using `material.transformUv()`? What do you expect that to do? Just use `intersects[0].uv` to get the point in the texture.